# Add context to existing tags with ActsAsTaggableOn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I've hunted SO and looked through the gem documentation and can't seem to find out how to add a context to a pre-existing tag.

My goal is to seed the DB with some tags for a specific context. From what I can tell, a tag needs to be created before it can be assigned a context.

```
tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.create(name: "name")
ActsAsAggableOn::Taggable.create(tag: tag.id, context: "context")
```

^That doesn't seem to work, since it throws and `undefined method create for ActsAsTaggableOn::Taggable`. I also cannot add context to the `Tag.create` method, since that throws an `unknown attribute: context` error.

I should mention that the context I'd like to add to the tags is set up in the appropriate model with: `acts_as_taggable_on :types`.

Any insight as to how to create a tag with a specific context? Or add it after a tag has been created?

Comment: Context is defined in taggings, not taggable (which is a module). But a tag is just a name, and has no context until something taggable is tagged, which creates a tagging. Given that, I'm not sure if you will be able to accomplish what you're looking to do.

Comment: @shannondoah thanks!